# YouTube live streaming captions - more than one language

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm currently live streaming a tv channel (beta phase yet) using YouTube.

- How do I add captions in more than 1 language for a live stream (with POST caption URL)?
- Even using just one language captions, how can I change the language? (The only option to the user - on web or app - is "EN" even if the caption is in other language)
- When using POST approach do send captions on live streams how/where to set/define duration of each subtitle?

Please don't refer this [url link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3068031?hl=en&vid=1-635780183579268315-2645708103). I know it already.

Comment: Are you already able to add captions and want to add more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can do only one language, if any at all. I have tried using the POST method YouTube describes on the page you link to - without success. Only get

> Result 299: "Error donwloading [...] Can't parse HTTP POST body."

Tried searching all kinds of support forums, but it seems no one has any advice and YouTube never replies to questions related to live caption. Including here...

Comment: you need to follow this specs: 

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6077032?&ref_topic=2853697&hl=pt-BR

If you are already following it, you need to check one important thing: the last line of the sequence must end with an empty line break! it's mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on [`contentDetails.closedCaptionsType`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.closedCaptionsType), you can embed captions in your video stream using the option `closedCaptionsEmbedded` and provide EIA-608 and/or CEA-708 formatted captions in your video from your encoder.

Sending multiple caption tracks muxed with your video with different languages specified by the "Language" tag on the caption stream should allow the user to switch between different captions in the web player.